# Sqlite Order by Before Group By Like Mysql

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, sql-order-by

I am working on a android sqlite db

I have 2 tables: chat, chat_messages

```
chat  
|_id |chatName      
 1   first
 2   second

chat_messages 
|_id |Chat_chatId |chatMessageContent |chatMessageId
 1      1         ttyl              4
 2      1         busy              3
 3      2         hi                2
 4      1         hi howdy          1
```

---

I want display a page showing latest chatMessageContent per chat
like below

```
result
|chatName |chatMessageContent  |chatMessageId 
first      ttyl                4
second     hi                  2
```

Since the  data restored from server was out of order, the latest chatMessageContent per chat need to follow chatMessageId desc

If Mysql the subquery works

```
Select * from (Select c._id,c.chatName,cm._id,cm.chatMessageContent,cm.chatMessageId from chat c, chat_message cm where cm.Chat_chatId = c._id order by cm.chatMessageId desc ) as lc GROUP BY lc.Chat_chatId
```

But it is not working for sqlite

Comment: huh? what is a point of GROUP BY without aggregate function? there is a DISTINCT

Comment: I am not familiar with DISTINCT, wasnt it works similar as GROUP BY??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.chatName, cm.chatMessageContent, cm.chatMessageId FROM chat_messages cm
INNER JOIN chat c ON c._id = cm.Chat_chatId
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(chatMessageId) as maxid, Chat_chatId FROM chat_messages GROUP BY Chat_chatId) AS t ON t.maxid=cm.chatMessageId
```

The subquery ensures that for each chat you get the max chatMessageId. By inner joining this to the chatmessages table, you eliminate all other chat messgaes and you can query the other fields as well from the chatmessages table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, I think this is one solution for you. It isn't the better solution, but..

```
SELECT * FROM chat_messages  t
JOIN chat c ON c._id = t.Chat_chatId
WHERE chatMessageId = (
    SELECT MAX(t2.chatMessageId) 
    FROM chat_messages  t2
    WHERE t2.Chat_chatId = t.Chat_chatId
)
```